# Facebook FriendPicker not shown (Facebook Android SDK Tutorial "Show Friends" are not up to date?)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I recently downloaded *facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0* and begun to develop an example-app with Facebook integration.

I'm following these tutorials on the Facebook Developers page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious

I have successfully implemented the first two parts, i.e. "Authenticate" and "Personalize". But now I'm totally stuck on the "Show Friends" tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends).

Step 2e works good, but from that to step 3c is not.

**The problem is that the friends picker is not shown at all**. When I touch the "With whom? Select friends" button, the activity is opened and I see the blue bar at the top with the title "Choose Friends" and the Done-button on the right. But the activity is otherwise white, i.e. without the list of friends.

By examining LogCat, I can't recognise any meaningful error or log messages.

I have read the tutorial through sentence by sentence for at least four times and compared to my implementation, and I just can't find the cause of why the friends picker is not shown. 
Have also tried to google for a cause and solution but without luck.

I would really appreciate if you can identify the problem and help me to solve this, so I can continue with the tutorial :)

Comment: I believe the tutorial you linked to was for v1.0 of the Graph API, whereas if you created your app after 04/30/2014, you're now using Graph API v2.0 (and you should get v3.14 of the Android SDK). In Graph API v2.0, you can only get a list of friends who are also using your app.

Comment: Yes, I created the app 05/07/2014. Do you mean that I should use v3.14 of the Facebook Android SDK in order to be able to complete the tutorial? Because the version I'm using now works with Graph API v2.0, right? But I can't get the list of friends the same way as in this tutorial?

Comment: What I mean is that v2.0 contains some fundamental differences to v1.0 (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), and while v3.8 of the SDK might work, it won't work properly for all APIs.

Comment: Thanks, now I've downloaded v3.14 and will try with that.

Comment: maybe this will be helpful to you check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543822/facebook-friend-picker-sdk-sample-not-working-android

Comment: maybe this will be helpful to you check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543822/facebook-friend-picker-sdk-sample-not-working-android

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is request the permission for LoginButton default.
Declarate the public global LoginButton in SplashFragment and setReadPermission();
for example:

```
private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
                if(i==SPLASH){
                    SplashFragment sf=(SplashFragment)fragments[i];      sf.login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends"));
                    //Log.d("TEST","Permission Set");
                }
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```