# Facebook Graph API: Attend to event always returns nothing with response code 200

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook graph api to get friends list
I am always getting

{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}

permissions are :
[installed, public_profile, read_stream, read_mailbox, publish_actions, user_likes, user_friends]

Please suggest me any way to get friends data.

Comment: If you are using Facebook API v2.0 which you have to if you created the app after 4/30/2014 /me/friends will only return friends that are also using the app.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Dude even i had the same issue and finally got the solution by myself. Check my answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543822/facebook-friend-picker-sdk-sample-not-working-android/23606183#23606183). The recent release of facebook SDK restricted several access and permissions. But still you can fetch friends list by using sdk 3.0 that can be found [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos). Download sendRequestHowto Sample from the above link.

Comment: thanks buddy to tell me this Now I am getting friends list in a dialog, But I want to get all my friends list in GraphUser object, "List<GraphUser> users", is there any way ..?

Comment: RequestsDialogBuilder only for app request to the friends, I am using FriendPickerFragment and adding it to my application, this class has friendPickerFragment.loadData(false); which is also unable to get list of friends, if You know then please share that reason, thanks you..

Comment: Even i tried the same using FriendPickerFragment. But for that you need to submit the app for verification as similar to Google play listing. Then you could able to fetch friends list. Refer facebook docs for further infos

Answer (score 0):

To get events, you must have current events on facebook. Check your profile first for events.